# Java countdown timer minutes and seconds

Tags: java, timer, countdown

I have already written a 60 seconds countdown timer but I would like to transform this to have a minutes and seconds timer like `mm:ss`.

Can I rearrange this existing code to get that ?

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    int i = 60;
    public void run(){
        if (i >= 0) {
            lab3.setText("Timer " + i--);
        }
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Well, it can be done, but what is stopping *you* from doing it? What have you tried? You did try something, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to display remaining number of second `i` in format `mimutes:seconds` format. If you assume that there are always 60 seconds in a minute:

```
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d", i / 60, i % 60);
System.out.println(time);
```